# How can I host WCF services in _vti_bin?

Tags: 2013, wcf

I am converting a feature from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.  Part of my project is to convert my feature from the old style manifest, ddf, makecab method to the newer Visual Studio SharePoint project with mapped folders.  In our old implementation, we hosted all of our files in 14/TEMPLATE/FEATURES/PROJ and made virtual directories in IIS through code to access our WCF services.  I'm now trying to eliminate our need for IIS virtual folders by deploying our WCF to 15/ISAPI/PROJ.

When I add myservice.svc to 15/ISAPI/PROJ, and try to access it from `http://myserver/_vti_bin/PROJ/myservice.svc`, I get redirected to /_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx.  I thought that maybe my problem was that I need to add a web.config to ISAPI/PROJ (we never needed one with the IIS virtual directory, so I never thought to add it here).  When I add the web.config and debug the Silverlight code that calls the service, I get a Not Found error on the async _completed call.

My SVC file looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Project.WCF.WCFServices.WorkFlowData" CodeBehind="WorkFlowData.svc.cs" %>
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to use the SharePoint provided ServiceHostFactory to create the appropriate endpoints for your service.

Look at this tutorial for the Service Host Factories available:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521581(v=office.14).aspx

- SOAP = MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory
- REST = MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory
- Data Service = MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory

Comment: we're currently creating endpoints dynamically in Silverlight, but I will take a look at this.

Comment: When I use a factory, I get Endpoint not found.

Comment: The link is broken :(